# Modifying Date Slider for android

Tags: android

I am trying to modify [Dateslider for Android](https://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/) to be only a time slider.

I have reduced it to

[image]

What I want is when time is "17:00" 17 should be in the middle instead of a bit to right.

Basically what I want is to put a pointer at the time selected. It would be easier to put it in middle like this

[image]

So my question goes to someone who has already used this lib. understands it a bit better than me and can help me out here.

PS: I believe it has got to something with `ScrollLayout.java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it, the present algo scrolls the current time to middle. But interesting part is the current timeview is 90( multiplied by dp factor depending on screen ) so it scrolls to middle of timeview and hence the time in bold appears to right. So we need to scroll an additional
"objWidth/2" . in short modify these 2 lines in `ScrollLayout.java`

### in setTime() function

original   `int left = (getChildCount()/2)*objWidth-getScrollX()`
to
modified `int left = (getChildCount()/2)*objWidth-getScrollX()+objWidth/2;`

### in reScrollTo() function [towards the end]

original `int left = (getChildCount()/2)*objWidth-scrollX;`
to
modified `int left = (getChildCount()/2)*objWidth-scrollX+objWidth/2;`

### then just place your indicator at displayWidth/2

Comment: can you plz send the code for the above UI with the library on nikhil.salunke969@gmail.com